# Limit number of results in group (AQL)

Tags: arangodb

I have the following working AQL query:

```
FOR d IN task FILTER d.listId == @listId &&  d.appAccountId == @appAccountId &&  (@serviceId IN d.visibleOnTenants.tenants[*].serviceId || !d.visibleOnTenants.tenants)   
COLLECT groupId=d.status.statusId  INTO groupByType


SORT groupId 
RETURN {
        groupId,
        tasks: groupByType[*].d,
        tasksNo: LENGTH(groupByType[*].d)
    }
```

Now I want to LIMIT the results, but per group, let's say on max 10 tasks per groupId.
Having `LIMIT 0.10` after `SORT groupId` limit number of groups, but I need limit of tasks per group.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all matching documents are already aggregated, you could do a simple [SLICE()](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-array.html#slice) to take the first 10 elements from each group:

```
RETURN {
    groupId,
    tasks: SLICE(groupByType, 0, 10)[*].d, // first 10
    tasksNo: LENGTH(groupByType[*].d)      // full count
}
```

Another syntactic option is to use an [inline limit](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/advanced-array-operators.html#inline-limit):

```
tasks: groupByType[* LIMIT 10].d,
```

The most verbose variant using a standard `LIMIT` would be to use a subquery:

```
tasks: (FOR g IN groupByType LIMIT 5 RETURN g.d),
```

The subquery has its own scope and `LIMIT` is restricted to this scope.